# Validate start date should be less than end date in Yii

Tags: php, validation, date, yii

My table has (among other columns) a start date and end date. I need to validate that the start date is less than the end date in Yii.

Do I validate that?

Answer (score 19):

Use the [CCompareValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCompareValidator) for [comparison validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation) in the rules() method of your model:

```
array(
  'event_end_date',
  'compare',
  'compareAttribute'=>'event_start_date',
  'operator'=>'>', 
  'allowEmpty'=>false , 
  'message'=>'{attribute} must be greater than "{compareValue}".'
),
```

Comment: @siddharth : something other than thanks i might appreciate. Not only me but anyone.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow. only do if the answer did work.

Comment: Can also use `{compareAttribute}` in order to show the comparison attribute's label, rather than the value.

I had the same question, this answered it. Thanks ayush.